# Powermock + Mockito not working

Tags: java, mockito, powermock

Trying to use Powermock to mock out a static method on SystemTray. Not sure why this isn't working. I've checked the match of Powermock -> Mockito versions, and I think I've followed all the steps for adding the right annotations, and using the correct PowerMock methods to setup the static one.

The static method on SystemTray seems to be called without the stubbed functionality set by the when().

I am mixing Powermock and Mockito calls here, but according to the docs that is correct.

```
package CommissionChecker;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
import org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils;

import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mockStatic;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(SystemTray.class)
public class DisplayManagerTest {

    @Mock
    Log logMock;
    @Mock
    Runner runnerMock;

    @Test
    public void display_manager_does_nothing_if_system_tray_is_not_supported() throws IOException, AWTException {
        mockStatic(SystemTray.class);
        when(SystemTray.isSupported()).thenReturn(false);

        new DisplayManager(runnerMock);

        verifyZeroInteractions(runnerMock);
    }
}
```

These are my maven dependencies

```
    <powermock.version>1.5.2</powermock.version>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>${powermock.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
        <version>${powermock.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just needed to change this line

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
```

to

```
@RunWith(DisplayManager.class)
```

According to this https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockSystem

Comment: Don't see how that works unless DisplayManager extends Runner.

Comment: @MattCampbell yeah lol I see what you're saying. This was like 6 years ago though. My guess is I made it stop running with the runner and that helped somehow :\

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple example using PowerMock:

```
package test;

import static org.easymock.EasyMock.expect;
import static org.easymock.EasyMock.replay;
import static org.easymock.EasyMock.verify;
import static org.testng.Assert.*;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
import org.testng.IObjectFactory;
import org.testng.annotations.ObjectFactory;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import demo.powermock.IdGenerator;
import demo.powermock.ServiceRegistartor;
//import org.easymock.classextension
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(IdGenerator.class)
public class Test111 {
    @ObjectFactory
    public IObjectFactory getObjectFactory() {
        return new org.powermock.modules.testng.PowerMockObjectFactory();
    }

    @Test
    //@org.testng.annotations.Test
    public void testRegisterService() throws Exception {
        long expectedId = 42;

        // We create a new instance of test class under test as usually.
        ServiceRegistartor tested = new ServiceRegistartor();

        // This is the way to tell PowerMock to mock all static methods of a
        // given class
        PowerMock.mockStatic(IdGenerator.class);

        /*
         * The static method call to IdGenerator.generateNewId() expectation.
         * This is why we need PowerMock.
         */
        expect(IdGenerator.generateNewId()).andReturn(expectedId);

        // Note how we replay the class, not the instance!
        PowerMock.replay(IdGenerator.class);

        long actualId = new ServiceRegistartor().registerService();

        // Note how we verify the class, not the instance!
        PowerMock.verify(IdGenerator.class);

        // Assert that the ID is correct
        assertEquals(expectedId, actualId);
    }
}
```

Comment: the above example is a very simple one to use

Comment: dude you just did copy paste, why don't you put some time and explain it a bit.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem but I added the import manually the problem disappeared.

```
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
```